# google url shortening not working

Tags: java, android, url-shortener, google-url-shortener

Hi i'm making an app where user can send cards to other user but when i click send i'm trying to use url shortening to send link but my url shortening is not working at all it always shows the error message url shortening failed
I did some research on SO but did not get a proper solution
I know something is not right but dont know which part is not right
below is my code for url shortening

```
 public void getShortenedUrl(String url, final int sendType){
            try {
                if (NetworkInfo.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
                    final boolean isMyCard=getArguments().getBoolean("isMyCard");
                    final String sharedTo=ceShareVia.getText().toString();
                    final String[] addresses = sharedTo.split(",");
                    LongUrl data = new LongUrl(url);
                    Call<LongUrl> cardResponseCall = ApiClientMain.getApiClient("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/")
                            .getShortenedUrl("application/json",ApplicationData.GOOGLE_URL_SHORTENER_KEY, data);
                    pbShare.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cardResponseCall.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<LongUrl>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<LongUrl> call, Response<LongUrl> response) {
                            pbShare.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            if (response != null && response.body() != null) {
                                String url = response.body().getId();
                                String message;
                                if(isMyCard) {
                                     message = "Hello," + "\n"
                                            + "Thanks for connecting!\n\n" + introMessage + "\n\n" + url + "\n\nRegards,\n"
                                            + preferenceManager.getPreferenceValues(PreferenceConstant.PERSON_NAME)
                                            + "\n" + "Have a nice day!";
                                }else {
                                    message = "Hello," + "\n"
                                            + "Thanks for connecting!\n\n" + introMessageOther + "\n\n" + url + "\n\nRegards,\n"
                                            + preferenceManager.getPreferenceValues(PreferenceConstant.PERSON_NAME)
                                            + "\n" + "Have a nice day!";
                                }


                                switch (sendType){
                                    case 0:
                                        sendEmail(addresses,"My Business Card",message);
                                        break;
                                    case 1:
                                        sendSms(sharedTo,message);
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        shareTextUrl(message);
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Url shortening failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<LongUrl> call, Throwable t) {
                            pbShare.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Url shortening failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

and here is model class for Long Url

```
public class LongUrl {
    @SerializedName("longUrl")
    @Expose
    private String longUrl;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("kind")
    @Expose
    private String kind;

    public String getLongUrl() {
        return longUrl;
    }

    public void setLongUrl(String longUrl) {
        this.longUrl = longUrl;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    public void setKind(String kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
    }

    public LongUrl(){

    }

    public LongUrl(String longUrl){
        this.longUrl = longUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Response or response.body. Are they null? You might want to try some more helpful messages while you dev. Could also try stepping through the code.

Comment: where do you think i'm going wrong

Comment: you should check the `Throwable t` to get the reason of the error

Answer (score 6):

Google URL Shortener is turned Down.

### OFFICIAL RELEASE

Starting March 30, 2018, we will be turning down support for goo.gl URL shortener. From April 13, 2018 only existing users will be able to create short links on the goo.gl console. You will be able to view your analytics data and download your short link information in csv format for up to one year, until March 30, 2019, when we will discontinue goo.gl. Previously created links will continue to redirect to their intended destination.

[Read this Blog for More Details.](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/transitioning-google-url-shortener.html)

If this is a New Project you cant create Shorten URL using the API

Comment: i have no idea about creating shortened url with new firebase api

Comment: Try it.. We Learn by using or trying it. Or Try some other URL Shortners like Bitly or OW.LY

Comment: Read the developers blog